# merTools bug: Error: class(merMod) %in% c("lmerMod",

Tags: r, debugging, package, libraries, lme4

`library(merTools)` has suddenly stopped working for me. While inputting a right `lmer` model into `plotFEsim(FEsim(model))`, I get this error:

```
Error: class(merMod) %in% c("lmerMod", "glmerMod", "blmerMod", "bglmerMod") is not TRUE
```

*I want to underline that the model inputted is right, so an example environment wouldn't help too much here. For reproduction, any `lmer` model with a couple of random and fixed effects should do.*

Comment: Can you reproduce it with a built-in dataset, and can you include your `sessionInfo()`? Wild hunch is that you have lmerTest attached, which masks the usual `lmer()` function.

Comment: I can get exactly this behaviour as suggested by @alexforrence by loading `lmerTest` and refitting/replotting ...

Comment: Thank you, alexforrence and Ben Bolker. Eventually the error was not really such--see answer. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just **re-** `install.packages('merTools')`, and it works again! (probably should have done that first, even though I'd only installed it a few days back).